# make view of array with filling input in the form

Tags: php, arrays, forms

i want make a view of array, in the first i need fill length of array for first form (this for how much  is show) and then i use that to fill value of array then i show that.

```
<form method="POST" action="prak_9_1.php">
input length of array <input type="text" name="bilangan">
<input type="submit" value="Hasil">
```

second code is different file

```
    <?php
    $bilangan = $_POST['bilangan'];
    $bil = $bilangan;
    $array = array();
    $n = 0;
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="prak_9_1.php">
    <?php
    for ($i=0; $i < $bilangan ; $i++) { 
    echo "input value of array : <input type='text' name='nilai_".$i."'><br>";
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Hasil">
    </form>
    <?php

    for ($i=0; $i < $bil ; $i++) { 
    $array[$n] = $_POST['nilai_'.$i];
    $n++; 
    }
    print_r($array);?>
```

sorry if my english is bad... thanks for ur helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first file :

```
<form method="POST" action="second.php">
    input length of array <input type="text" name="bilangan">
    <input type="submit" value="Hasil">
</form>
```

and second file :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['bilangan'])) {
    echo '<form method="POST">';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $_POST['bilangan']; $i++) {
       echo "input value of array : <input type='text' name='nilai[]'><br>";
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Hasil">';
    echo '</form>';
}

if (isset($_POST['nilai'])) {
    print_r($_POST['nilai']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful (_especially_ when OP explicitly says this is a homework problem). Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.